# WPF tooltip Binding getting override when I set the tooltip from code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a User control and I bind the tooltip of that control into some object's property

```
                        <usercontrols:ucButton x:Name="xSaveCurrentBtn" ButtonType="ImageButton" ButtonFontImageSize="16" ButtonImageWidth="18" ButtonImageHeight="18" ButtonImageType="Save" Click="xSaveSelectedButton_Click" ButtonStyle="{StaticResource $ImageButtonStyle_Menu}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                            <usercontrols:ucButton.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip Content="{Binding ItemName, Mode=OneWay}" ContentStringFormat="Save {0}"/>
                            </usercontrols:ucButton.ToolTip>
                        </usercontrols:ucButton>
```

from the code I set the data context of the ucButton to be my object:

```
xSaveCurrentBtn.DataContext = WorkSpace.Instance.CurrentSelectedItem;
```

sometimes the CurrentSelectedItem is null, and if this is the case I want the tooltip to display "No Item Selected"
I tried doing this:

```
xSaveCurrentBtn.Tooltip = "No Item Selected";
```

but when the CurrentSelectedItem isn't null and I reset the xSaveBtn.DataContext to that object, I am still seeing the No Item Selected tooltip as if my WPF tooltip section was overriden and its no longer binding into the datacontext ItemName Property

Comment: I maybe wrong, but I think, I can remember, that when you assign a value to a DependencyProperty that currently is binding to some other value - then you destroy that binding by the assignment. In order to keep the binding and still assign some value  you need to set that value using `SetCurrentValue` method. In your case: 
`xSaveCurrentBtn.SetCurrentValue(FrameworkElement.ToolTipProperty,"No Item Selected");`

Comment: Also: if you want special handling for the data object being `null` consider using the `TargetNullValue` property of the `BindingBase` class. It seems ideal for your task. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Thank you! I wasn’t familiar with the set current value method and the target null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a property to two values at the same time. It's impossible.
What you are doing in XAML is equivalent to:

```cs
    xSaveCurrentBtn.Tooltip = new ToolTip() {.....};
```

When you setting a string value to the same property, the previous value is lost. And it is not possible to restore it if you do not save it first.

You might want to assign a value in case of a binding error:

```xml
<ToolTip Content="{Binding ItemName,
                           Mode=OneWay,
                           FallbackValue='No Item Selected'}"
         ContentStringFormat="Save {0}"/>
```

> how can I bind the data context to update to be the new CurrentSelectedItem without explicitly setting it?

Assuming that «WorkSpace.Instance» is an immutable property that returns an instance of «WorkSpace» and «CurrentSelectedItem» is a property with an «INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged» notification, then you can do this:

```xml
<usercontrols:ucButton DataContext="{Binding CurrentSelectedItem, Source={x:Static viewmodels:WorkSpace.Instance}}" ...>
```

The «viewmodels» prefix depends on the assembly and namespace in which the «WorkSpace» class is declared.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation, I figured that what was happening but you made it clearer to me

Comment: Is it going to be "Save No Item Selected" in the edge case?

Comment: @ASh , If CurrentSelectedItem=null, then null has no properties and binding to the ItemName property will generate a binding error. In this case, the binding will return the value specified in FallbackValue.

Comment: @EldHasp, yes, I understand that. Content will be 'No Item Selected'. but after that ContentStringFormat should be applied and produce 'Save No Item Selected', right?

Comment: @ASh , Yes. That's right. If you need to change the ContentStringFormat depending on CurrentSelectedItem=null, then you need to use a trigger in the Style or Template.

Comment: @EldHasp, I would rather use ContentTemplate

Comment: @ASh , Of course, you can also use a data template. But in this case, when you need to display only one line, in my opinion, this is redundant.

Comment: Another question If I may, how can I bind the data context to update to be the new CurrentSelectedItem without explicitly setting it?

CurrentSelectedItem is a property of my WorkSpace class, and I listen to changes of that property, so if the CurrentSelectedItem has been changed, I am re-setting the xSaveCurrentBtn.DataContext to be CurrentSelectedItem again, how can I truly bind it so as soon as it changes, the data context will also be updated without explicitly setting it

Comment: @AmitAmir , Read the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ContentTemplate with TextBlock, which will either use StringFormat, or TargetNullValue depending on ItemName being `null`:

```
<usercontrols:ucButton.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Content="{Binding ItemName}">
        <ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat='Save {0}',
                                          TargetNullValue='No Item Selected'}"/>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
    </ToolTip>
</usercontrols:ucButton.ToolTip>
```

or if you bind Tooltip.Content differently:

```
<usercontrols:ucButton.ToolTip>
    <ToolTip Content="{Binding}">
        <ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemName,
                                          StringFormat='Save {0}',
                                          FallbackValue='No Item Selected'}"/>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </ToolTip.ContentTemplate>
    </ToolTip>
</usercontrols:ucButton.ToolTip>
```

Comment: TargetNullValue may be returned even if CurrentSelectedItem!=null if the ItemName property is set to null. That is, if CurrentSelectedItem=null, FallbackValue will be returned. But TargetNullValue will be returned when CurrentSelectedItem.ItemName=null.